# C pipe stdout to fork

Tags: c, linux, shell, pipe, fork

I am trying to write a C program that execute `ls | wc` using pipe and fork but I can't figure out what is wrong with my code. When I run the code below nothing is returned.

```
int main() {
    pid_t p1, p2;
    int fd1[2];

    pipe(fd1);

    p1 = fork();
    if (p1 == 0) {
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(fd1[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd1[0]);
        execlp("ls", "ls", (char *)NULL);
    } else {
        p2 = fork();

        if (p2 == 0) {
            dup2(fd1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fd1[0]);
            close(fd1[1]);

            execlp("wc", "wc", (char *)NULL);
        } else {
            waitpid(p2, 0, WUNTRACED);
            waitpid(p1, 0, WUNTRACED);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "nothing is returned"?

Comment: Side notes: Is there any reason for the asymmetry after both forks? Once you close the file descriptor that you want to `dup` to, the other time not. And is there a reason why you don't close the pipe file descriptors in the parent process? And what is the reason to pass `0` as second parameter `int *status` to `waitpid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't clearly explain what this program was doing that you considered to be wrong.  However, when I run this program myself (after adding the appropriate headers -- in the future, please don't leave those out of your question), it hangs until I press control-C.  I'm going to assume that this is what you didn't want, and that what you *did* want is for it to print the output of `wc` and then exit.

The program hangs because `fd1[1]` is still open in the parent process at the point when it calls `wait`.  `wc` will not receive an EOF indication until *all* of the file descriptors referring to the write side of the pipe are closed.  But the parent process is not going to close the write side of the pipe until both of its child processes exit, and `wc` is not going to exit until it gets an EOF, so you have a deadlock.

You need to add `close(fd1[1])` on the parent side of the first `if`, immediately before `p2 = fork()`.  That is sufficient to clear the deadlock.  You *should* also add `close(fd1[0])` on the parent side of the *second* `if`, immediately before the `waitpid` calls.  And you should also check all operations for errors.